# Where can I find stock Android apps that are not normally in the Market?

Tags: applications, 2.2-froyo, custom-roms, camera

I downloaded a custom ROM for my Samsung Captivate phone that is a variant of 2.2.1.  Its version of the Camera allows me to use the power button to take pictures.  I decided I want the stock camera without this feature.  Is there a site from which the default camera.apk is available for 2.2.1, or for that matter, other apps?

Comment: The best way is to the image for the original ROM and extract it.

Comment: @Matthew Read - I think you accidentally the verb. ;)

Comment: Haha.  Mount!  Mount the image.  Thanks @JonnyP

Comment: @matthew, how do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I just looked at the firmware for my Samsung Vibrant, you don't actually need to mount the image -- I was thinking of the recovery image or a nandroid backup.  The firmware (ROM) should be in a zip file, which you can open up and go to `/system/app/` and grab the camera.apk.  I'd put it on your phone's SD card, then use [Root Explorer](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.speedsoftware.rootexplorer) or similar to copy it into `/system/app/` on your device and overwrite the current one (which you may want to back up first).

You can check out [my answer to another question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7851/restore-only-part-of-nandroid-image/7860#7860) for info on mounting, but you shouldn't have to do that :)

Comment: Recent stock firmware is here if you don't have it: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1145149

Comment: Make sure that you are using applications that are compatible. For example, if your custom ROM is CM7, you may not be able to use the camera from a stock TouchWiz ROM. This is because the "core" of these ROM are completely different and could cause some issues. If you are using a ROM that is based on TouchWiz, however, you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks.  I just thought about restoring from my Titanium Backup as well, which has my stock apps.  Same idea.

Comment: @Chance TB doesn't back up system apps, just their data, at least by default.

Comment: @MatthewRead, TB can backup system apps, but you're right, it's not the default, and it's not always recommended across ROMs/phones.