# How to restore adb backup on Nexus 4 (boot loop)?

Tags: cyanogenmod, backup, adb, nexus-4, restore

Recently I have flashed unofficial cyanogenmod 10.2 for my Nexus 4. After testing some features I the device came into a "bootloop" (stays on cyanogenmod logo launcher).

I tried to reflash it with cm 10.1 (wipe dalvik cache and /cache partition) but the same effect.

Now I have completed the adb backup but if I restore it I get the same effect as described above.

I can launch the device successfully on clear cm 10.1 but it won't boot after restore of my backup. What can I do now ?

Answer (score 0):

Do not restore the full backup taken, but [Restore only part of it](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/7851/16575). And do it "piece by piece", so if the error re-occurs you at least know where it comes from and can skip the faulty part.

**Edit:** As I was not fully clear about where I pointed to: [Titanium Backup](http://www.appbrain.com/app/titanium-backup-%E2%98%85-root/com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) is capable of restoring parts from [nandroid](/questions/tagged/nandroid) as well as [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) backups.

Comment: While that is true, my answer there is still partly valid here (will update my answer to reflect that – sorry for confusion)