# Restore Images from TWRP nandroid backup

Tags: restore, nandroid, virtualbox

My (rooted) HTC U Ultra died, not repairable - motherboard issue. I have a Galaxy S20, but want to get photos etc that were in internal storage. I have a nandroid backup taken with TWRP a few months ago a well as Titanium Backup taken on the same day. From what I understand Titanium backup does not backup data (images etc) from internal storage, so I have been looking at how I can use the nandroid backup which is a backup the entire system at a partition level.

I consider myself a novice, but I tried to restore the Ultra backup to my old HTC One M9+ (it was worth a try), this did not work because internal storage is too small, got a Error 255 and it went to a boot loop. I read in another question the nandroid backup can be opened up using 7zip.

I searched the backup file but could not find anything that resembled the images or my data, most of the files are human unreadable. Do these files need to be compiled to make them readable? Or once opened in 7zip is there a viewer app/program to read them?

Is it possible to restore the nandroid backup into a virtual space which is not device specific, like virtual box?

Any suggestions or advise would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can mount nandroid backup and extract the contained files. On Linux you can mount the image, on Windows you can try ext4 reading software.

Comment: you need to pull backup of Internal Storage or (decrypted) userdata partition from the device. guess you did not do that beforehand. if your device died then that data is lost

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I backup media, game data (internal storage) using TWRP?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/200713/how-do-i-backup-media-game-data-internal-storage-using-twrp)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restore only part of nandroid image](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7851/restore-only-part-of-nandroid-image)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had a look at these options but could not restore the images or access them. There are 3 files in the Nandroid backup that could contain the data. I tried to use Titanium Backup to restore only these files to my HTC One M9+, the restore completed successfully but no images. Also tried to restore the data partition but this put the M9+ into a boot loop. Without another HTC U Ultra to a full restore not sure if i can get them back.